# How to read column from text file and store them accordingly?

Tags: matlab, file, matrix

I am trying to read a text file with two columns and store it in a matrix. First column is **id** and second column is the **value**. However the id elements are not in order. I want to read the file and have a 2D matrix where each id is assigned to its corresponding values. For example if the txt file is like this:

```
id    value
=======
1    45
2    83
4    37
3    56
1    73
4    91
```

I want the matrix to be like this:

```
1    45,73
2    83
3    56
4    37,91
```

I have something like this but it doesn't work:

```matlab
infile = 'txtfile.txt';
data = importdata(infile);
id = data(:,1); % column 1 of the data text file is assigned the variable x
value = data(:,2); % column 2 is assigned the variable y

xvalues = zeros(max(id),1000);

for i = 1:length(id)
    for j = 1:max(id)
        if i==j
            xvalues(j) = [xvalues(j) ,value(i)];
        end
    end
end
```

It says:

> Unable to perform assignment because the left and right sides have a different number of elements.

for this line:

```
xvalues(j) = [xvalues(j) ,value(i)];
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: in any asigment `size(left)` has to be `size(right)` of course, you can not put more things in less space. in your case, `size(xvalues(j)` is not the same as `size([xvalues(j) ,value(i)])` obviously, so you can not put one into the other. This is quite basic, I suggest a matlab toturial to understand this things better.

Comment: I wanted to append the **values** to the corresponding **id** in the matrix. Because the length of each row of matrix is variable, since an ID can have any number of values. Is there any way?

Comment: You can not have a matrix in matlab with variable sizes per row, that is, by definition, not a matrix.

Comment: OK, if I wanted to fix it to 1000, then how could I append new values to each row?

Comment: You could append zeros/nan's to create a matrix with empty values. Alternatively, create a cell array, which can handle such an input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Please read through the comments**

```
% Given Data
data =  [1 45;2 83;4 37;3 56;1 73;4 91];

id = data(:, 1);
value = data(:,2);


% Find the number occurences of each index
occurence = histcounts(id);

% Fill xvalues with nan as 0 is also a number 
% Don't waste memory, by setting the column to the maximum occurence + 1
% First column is for the index
xvalues = nan.*zeros(max(id),max(occurence)+1);


    for i = 1:max(id)
        % First column is the index
        xvalues(i, 1) = i;

        % Start filling column with value at column 2
        k = 2;

        for j = 1: length(id)
            if i == id(j)

                xvalues(i, k) = value(j);

                %   Used in case there is any repeating value        
                k = k + 1;
            end
        end
    end
```

**Output**

```
xvalues =

     1    45    73
     2    83   NaN
     3    56   NaN
     4    37    91
```

Answer (score 1):

A possible version using [**cell array**](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html)

```
%% test data
data=[
1    45
2    83
4    37
3    56
1    73
4    91
];

% split original matrix for convenience
indices = data(:,1) ;
values  = data(:,2) ;

% Find unique indices and their row position
[uid ,ia,ic] = unique(indices) ;
% find number of unique indices
nuid = numel(uid) ;

% pre-allocate cell array
C = cell(nuid,1) ;
% assign all the values corresponding to each row ine
for k=1:nuid
    C{k} = values(ic == k) ;
end
```

will give you a cell array:

[image]